# Python hadoop mapreduce job using mrjob subprocess.CalledProcessError

Tags: python, hadoop, mrjob

I am trying to run basic example from the mrjob's website on my custom data. I have run Hadoop map reduce successfully using streaming, I have also successfully tried the script without Hadoop, but now I am trying to run it on Hadoop via mrjob by following command.

```
./mapred.py -r hadoop --hadoop-bin /usr/bin/hadoop -o hdfs:///user/cloudera/wc_result_mrjob hdfs:///user/cloudera/books
```

Source code of mapred.py is following:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

from mrjob.job import MRJob


class MRWordFrequencyCount(MRJob):

    def mapper(self, _, line):
        yield "chars", len(line)
        yield "words", len(line.split())
        yield "lines", 1

    def reducer(self, key, values):
        yield key, sum(values)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MRWordFrequencyCount.run()
```

Unfortunately I am getting following error:

```
no configs found; falling back on auto-configuration
no configs found; falling back on auto-configuration
creating tmp directory /tmp/mapred.cloudera.20140824.195414.420162
writing wrapper script to /tmp/mapred.cloudera.20140824.195414.420162/setup-wrapper.sh
STDERR: mkdir: `hdfs:///user/cloudera/tmp/mrjob/mapred.cloudera.20140824.195414.420162/files/': No such file or directory
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./mapred.py", line 18, in <module>
MRWordFrequencyCount.run()
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/mrjob/job.py", line 494, in run
mr_job.execute()
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/mrjob/job.py", line 512, in execute
super(MRJob, self).execute()
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/mrjob/launch.py", line 147, in execute
self.run_job()
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/mrjob/launch.py", line 208, in run_job
runner.run()
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/mrjob/runner.py", line 458, in run
self._run()
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/mrjob/hadoop.py", line 238, in _run
self._upload_local_files_to_hdfs()
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/mrjob/hadoop.py", line 265, in _upload_local_files_to_hdfs
self._mkdir_on_hdfs(self._upload_mgr.prefix)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/mrjob/hadoop.py", line 273, in _mkdir_on_hdfs
self.invoke_hadoop(['fs', '-mkdir', path])
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/mrjob/fs/hadoop.py", line 109, in invoke_hadoop
raise CalledProcessError(proc.returncode, args)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/usr/bin/hadoop', 'fs', '-mkdir', 'hdfs:///user/cloudera/tmp/mrjob/mapred.cloudera.20140824.195414.420162/files/']' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

It seems to me that mrjob is not able to create some directory in HDFS, but unfortunately I don't know how to fix this problem.

My Hadoop is the cloudera CDH5.1. quickstart.

Thank you in advance for any suggestions and advices.

**EDIT:**

I have tried to run the same code on cloudera CDH4.7. quickstart and it worked well. So my modified question is: Is cloudera CDH5.1. supported by mrjob framework? If so, then how to run it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I encountered the same error, the workaround I did was to change the :

`self.invoke_hadoop(['fs', '-mkdir', path])`

to

`self.invoke_hadoop(['fs', '-mkdir','-p', path])`

The file modified was :
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/mrjob/hadoop.py

My MRJOB have been running for couple of months now without any troubles, so this looks fine to me.

I am myself keen to know alternative for the same.